# Is there an overview about the different rewards for the Card Mastery feature in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

Recently the Card Mastery Add-On was released in Clash Royale.
First I was astonished about where all my gold suddenly came from. Then I noticed, that for some masteries you get cards as reward. However like, e.g. at donating cards, having maximized a specific card, will replace the value (e.g. 40.000 for a legendary one).

My question is what are the rewards for the different kind of cards?

The ingame menu only shows me the rewards for the next card level:

[image: CoC Card mastery]

Supercell itself only talks about general rewards and does not point to any specific information: https://help.supercellsupport.com/clash-royale/en/articles/card-mastery.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Card Masteries have a set of rewards based on the rarity of the card itself.

---

The [Clash Royale Fandom page](https://clashroyale.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Mastery) has 2 tables showing the rewards for the first and second task set:

[image]

Comment: Nice. Haven't found this!